# The array from another class doesn't update when scanner is used

Tags: java, arrays

When I try to use scanner on another class I can't update the array.

```
private int numClients;
private int[] clients;
```

These are variables from my class Rooms.

```
public Hotel(String name, int numRooms, int numClients){
    this.name = name;
    this.numRooms = numRooms;
    this.numClients= numClients;
    this.clients = new int[numClients];
}
```

Of course I added setters and getters:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setNaziv(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getNumRooms() {
    return numRooms;
}

public void setNumRooms(int numRooms) {
    this.numRooms = numRooms;
}

public int getNumClients() {
    return numClients;
}

public void setNumClients(int numClients) {
    this.numClients = numClients;
}
```

When I tried to add it to test it in another class, name and numRooms change. numClients change too but array doesn't update.

```
Hotel h1 = new Hotel(" ", 0, 0);

String name= sc.nextLine();
h1.setName(name);

int numRooms= sc.nextInt();
h1.setNumRooms(numRooms);

int numClients= sc.nextInt();
h1.numClients(numClients);

h1.show();
```

This is the show method:

```
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
    System.out.println("Rooms: " + this.numRooms);
    System.out.println("Number of clients: " + this.numClients);
    for(int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(clients[i]);
    }
}
```

*Maybe there will be some typing errors I translated the var names to English for question purposes.*

Comment: Are you trying to set an int to an array? Show us your `numClients` function because thats not a setter.

Comment: Can you show us the setter method for the clients array ?

Comment: While I was translating the names of variables etc. i forgot to add setNumClients. In code it is actually setting it.

Comment: So, in which function do you update your array ? I don't see such method.

Comment: I suspect you think the line `this.clients = new int[numClients];` in the `Hotel` constructor means that `clients` is a variable-length array whose length is "magically" tied to the value of `numClients`.  Not true:  If you want the size of the array to change when `numClients` changes, then you need to must re-create the array at the new length.in `setNumClients`.

Comment: @kali  I don't have a function that updates my array, should I and how do I create it?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Do I do it through new method or? It seems from all the answers is that after the user types in the new variable I should somehow update the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix this without updating and making new methods is defining values with scanner and putting it into constructor.

```
public void test(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type in the name of Hotel: ");
        String name= sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type in number of rooms: ");
        int numRooms = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Type in the number of clients");
        int numClients= sc.nextInt();

        Hotel h1 = new Hotel(name, numRooms, numClients);
        

        h1.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the array, it's size is fixed. You can test this with a few rows:

```
int size = 10; // Start with size 10
int[] array = new int[size]; // Array is 10 elements long
System.out.println(size); // Prints 10
System.out.println(array.length); // Also prints 10
size = 1000; // Change size ??
System.out.println(size); // Prints 1000
System.out.println(array.length); // Still prints 10
```

Output:

```
10
10
1000
10
```

You also don't appear to actually set any elements in the array in your code. That would be something like

```
h1.getClients()[0] = 3;
```

**Edit**

When this line in your constructor is exectuted:

```
this.clients = new int[numClients];
```

The array is created with the size that `numClients` has **right at that moment**. After that, there is no relation between `numClients` and `clients` anymore.

You would need to create a new array, copy contents (if you want to preserve it) and reassign clients with the new array in order to change the size.

You can do this with `Arrays.copyOf()` :

```
int newLength = 20;
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength);
System.out.println(array.length); // Prints 20!!
```

Comment: I see, but the problem is, when I don't use the scanner and type it manually in constructor it prints out normally when I use show method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The array is created by the constructor. So whatever value you set in the constructor will be the arrays size. If you were to read the values from the `Scanner` first and then call the constructor with those values, you should get the same result.

Comment: Added sample for copying the array to a new array with new length.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will run once for a single object. So, if you want to add more values in the clients array then a method is a must.
The main Class:

```
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hotel hotel = new Hotel("romeo",5,10);
    hotel.addClients(6);
    hotel.addClients(10);
    hotel.addClients(5);
    hotel.show();
  }
}
```

The Hotel Class:

```
class Hotel{
  private int numRooms,numClients;
  private String name;
  private int clients[] = new int[10];

  public Hotel(String name, int numRooms, int numClients){
    this.name = name;
    this.numRooms = numRooms;
    this.numClients= numClients;
    this.clients[0] = numClients;
}
```

The method to add Clients in the clients array:

```
public void addClients(int numClients){
  for(int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
    if(clients[i] == 0){
      clients[i] = numClients;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Show method output:

```
Name: romeo
Rooms: 5
Number of clients: 10
10
6
10
5
```

The Total number of clients can be found by summation of the clients array.
To make the array dynamic, the linked list data structure can be applied.